# ¿Cómo hago un if para comprobar si NO se ha seleccionado un radiobooton?

Tags: java

quisiera saber como puedo realizar un if que compruebe que no se ha seleccionado un radio botón,

```
if(){
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Debe seleccionar al menos un gupo");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Necesitas referenciar el boton `JRadioButton` mediante

```
nombreDelBoton.isSelected()
```

que te devolverá un booleano diciendo si esta seleccionado o no